# Highly Available Bot in multiple regions using bot framework

Tags: botframework, chatbot

We are planning to use Microsoft Bot framework to develop bot. We are having large user base in different countries which we want to cater through bot. Theoretically, We would like deploy bot service in different regions (so there there would be less latency) but still, there should be one single bot rather than having country specific bot.

Behind the scene, bot which I would be  writing,  will call API(services) of my web application.

As there is traffic manager is used for highly available systems deployed in different regions, will it be the same thing in case of bot service?

Comment: A bot is simply a Web API, so you would manage it the same as you would any Web API.

Comment: @JasonSowers Thanks for your response Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JasonSowers is right. Bot Framework SDK for C# is built with Web API, and Bot Framework SDK for Nodejs is built with `restify`. Both are all basically web applications. You can deploy your bot application on any web services who support cross regions. E.G. You can leverage Azure Web Apps for this requirement, please refer to [Run a web application in multiple regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/app-service-web-app/multi-region) on Azure.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Liu Thanks for your detailed response.